# IdentityServer4 - RefreshToken Expiration

Tags: identityserver4

Is there a way to achieve following flow using IdentityServer4
If a client is not active for a specified amount of time - he should not be able to refresh his token.
As I understand this should be achievable via RefreshTokenExpiration settings, but I don't understand what specific combination of settings should allow this behavior.
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html - This is the official documentation, but none of the combination I tried helped me achieve my goal

Answer (score 0):

Here is settings required:

```
RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 10000,
```

[Here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Services/Default/DefaultRefreshTokenService.cs#L212) is when update token happens on code